# is there any way in Python to complete all the iteration of for loop even if expection block return -1 for one iteration?

Tags: python, for-loop, exception

```
def try():
    for i in range(9):
        try:
           {body}
        except:
            return -1
```

According to my understanding if an exception occurs for any iteration the program will exit the loop and return -1 without completing the whole loop. I want the program to complete the rest of the loop even if an exception occurs for any iteration.

Is there any way of doing that?

Comment: So don't put a `return` inside the `except` block

Comment: There's not enough info to know exactly how you want this to function, but you can just `pass` on an exception. `return` will _always_ break out of the function, and therefore the loop too

Comment: What your asking for doesn't make sense. A return statement *exits the function and returns control to the caller*. That's what it does. So no, you can't have your cake and eat it too. Perhaps you can describe the overall behavior you require, and people can suggest some way to accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

You could place a continue instead of return, like this:

```
def tryTest():
    s=0
    for i in range(9):
        try:
           s+=1/(i-3)
        except:
            continue
    return s
  
print(tryTest())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
xlist=[1,2,'THREE',4,5]
print(xlist)

for item in xlist:

    try:
        xlist[xlist.index(item)] = item / 5
    except:
        xlist[xlist.index(item)] = item
    finally:
        print(item)

print(xlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pass` and `continue` for the purpose

If you want your statement executed after `try-except` block use `pass`

If you want to continue with the next iteration, use `continue`

For instance:

```
def try():
    for i in range(9):
        try:
           {body}
        except:
            pass
        print('execute')
```

If you want to `print('execute')` you should use `pass`.

```
def try():
    for i in range(9):
        try:
           {body}
        except:
            continue
```

Since there is no statement to execute after `except` you could use `continue`, but using `pass` won't change the logic.